# Unity Collaborate to Plastic SCM automatic migration: "client.conf" error

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, migration, plasticscm

##### Background

- macOS 11.6
- Unity Hub 3.0.1
- Unity 2021.2.10f1
- Version Control 1.15.12.
- No Plastic SCM version was previously installed on this macOS device.

##### Issue

After clicking "migrate" in a Unity prompt asking to migrate the project from Collaborate to Plastic SCM, the following error has appeared:

```
CmClientException: The client configuration file "client.conf" contains errors: Root element is missing.
```

The Plastic SCM tab in Unity does not show any information, and simply states "An unexpected error has occurred", with a sole option "Reload", upon clicking which, I get the following error:

```
Cancelling Display Dialog : This should not be called when a View's DrawRect Method is in progress
```

Trying to solve this issue, I have installed Plastic SCM Cloud version, but when I try to run the "PlasticSCM.app", I get the same first error ("client.conf" error: Root element is missing).

Comment: Love the name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Solution from Unity Plastic SCM Support Team

The *client.conf* file in question is located in a hidden directory:

```
/Users/<USERNAME>/.plastic4
```

You should rename/delete the *client.conf* file with all GUIs closed so that it rebuilds on the next (Unity) start.

##### Additional option

You could also give a try PlasticXSCM, a multi platform client with a couple of useful features.